# different increment everytime i create

Tags: mysql, laravel, auto-increment

so I have this table. i want to create project with different id but it have to be in same table so i make 2 different id type.

```
|--------------------------------------|
|id | idtype1 | idtype2 | Project_name |
|--------------------------------------|
```

if I create a project with idtype1, the idtype1 increment but idtype2 still

```
|--------------------------------------|
|id | idtype1 | idtype2 | Project_name |
|--------------------------------------|
| 1 |    1    |    0    |     name1    |
| 2 |    2    |    0    |     name2    |
|--------------------------------------|
```

but if I create a project with idtype2 it does the opposite

```
|--------------------------------------|
|id | idtype1 | idtype2 | Project_name |
|--------------------------------------|
| 1 |    1    |    0    |     name1    |
| 2 |    2    |    0    |     name2    |
| 3 |    0    |    1    |     name3    |
| 4 |    0    |    2    |     name4    |
|--------------------------------------|
```

is this possible ? and how ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do AUTO_INCREMENT here, because sometimes idType1 needs to be incremented and 2 not. So, in your migrations do:

```
$table->Integer('idType1');
$table->Integer('idType2');
```

When register new project, calculate +1 in the associated column as needed.

EDIT #1

```
if (project_type == 1) {
       DB::table('projects_controller')->increment('idType1');
} elseif (project_type == 2) {
       DB::table('projects_controller')->increment('idType2');
} etc etc
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want three columns: id, idtype1, and idtype2 to all automatically increment? If so, you can define that in the migration with $table->increments('idtype1'); as described on https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations.  However, it is worth noting that all three columns will then always have the same values as each other, so you might want to rethink why you want all three columns.

idtype1 and idtype2 are very vague and don't convey any meaning. What do these represent? Things will improve if you can convey what they represent in their name.

Are these ids of related records in other tables? If so, you should name them with the other table name, e.g. type_id or address_id.

You can also then look into setting up foreign key information so that the database will be aware of the relationship and help enforce the integrity for you.

Comment: if I explains what I use the idtype for it makes the question even more confusing. also if I put automatic increment it will add value every time I create but instead, I only want them to increase at a specific time only. idtype is only a replacement name so the question make sense I didn't use idtype in my real table.

Comment: "if I explains what I use the idtype for it makes the question even more confusing" This is a sign that your solution is making things more complicated than it needs to be. I believe this question to be an x/y problem. You are trying to solve a complex problem in a specific way, and asking for help with an aspect of that solution. Instead, rethink the problem and look for help on a better solution. 

Specific to the question, if you only want those fields to increment in certain cases, you need to write code to make the decision and manually set the value in your insert statement every time.

Comment: "you need to write code to make the decision and manually set the value in your insert statement every time" thats why im here